# Dynamic Drools Endpoint Update in Drools Camel Server

Tags: apache-camel, drools, kie

The "User Guide" for Drools 6 states that a camel endpoint for drools shall be in the below format:

```
<to uri="kie:{1}/{2}" />
```

where

- `{1}`: Execution Node identifier that is registered in the `CamelContext`
- `{2}`: Knowledge Session identifier that was registered in the Execution Node with identifier `{1}`

***Doubt # 1 :***

If the sessions are created before the endpoints are built, how the incremental changes in kmodule will be picked up by the sessions created before?

Statement about KScanner from the document:

> If the KieScanner finds, in the Maven repository, an updated version
>   of the Kie project used by that KieContainer it automatically
>   downloads the new version and triggers an incremental build of the new
>   project. **From this moment** all the **new KieBases and KieSessions created**
>   from that KieContainer will use the new project version.

***Doubt # 2***

And..I am trying to configure this endpoint to route to ksessions dynamically.

Traversing through the source code, I tried declaring the uri to `kie:dynamic` and adding new sessions to `KieEndpoint.executorsByName`, like

```
KieEndpoint endPoint = (KieEndpoint)camel.getEndpoint("kie:dynamic");
endPoint.executorsByName.put(sessionName, kSession);
```

Is this the right way of adding the dynamic sessions? I didn't find any hint in user guide for this.