# Scope of Dynamic KnowledgeSessions - drools-camel-server

Tags: apache-camel, drools, jbpm, kie

***Env: Drools v6***

How does drools-camel manage the scopes of KnowledgeSessions, in general, may it be stateful or stateless?

And I would like to know esp. the scope management of **dynamic** knowledge sessions.

is it org.kie.camel.component.KiePolicy or KieEndpoint ?

Kindly refer to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526313/dynamic-drools-endpoint-update-in-drools-camel-server) on how dynamic knowledge sessions has to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create your sessions manually in your own service and define your own polices based on what you are trying to solve. The camel server in 6 was just an example and one of the many options of how to create a drools service.

HTH